# Neo4j Load CSV import with custom local path in MacOS is not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using MacOS.
I have a csv file on a random directory.

In the neo4j configuration file I have already made the updates so that it allows importing files from any path:

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
#dbms.directories.import=import
```

Now I'm trying to do:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/me/Documents/api/data/objectsForNeo.csv'
AS row
RETURN count(*)
```

and I get

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/Users/me/Documents/api/data/objectsForNeo.csv ()
```

I do NOT want to have to move the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Imports must be located in a folder relative to your import folder (which you have commented out in your config). You can't just arbitrarily access files from anywhere in your file system. So in your case, you could set the import folder to either of these:

```
dbms.directories.import=/Users/me/Documents/api
dbms.directories.import=/Users/me/Documents/api/data
```

Then you would have either of these, respectively:

```sql
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/objectsForNeo.csv'
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///objectsForNeo.csv'
```

Comment: thank you, but same error unfortunately. Is there a way to get a more specific error?